# is it possible to convert array itself as a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

for example, 
in a function fc(obj)

In order to convert into a string, I used

```
if (typeof(obj) === 'string'){
    return `"${obj}"`
```

but is it possible to convert ["hi"] into "["hi"]"? perhaps use recursion function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`. It should work like you want it to for arrays. Example:

```js
let arr = ["item"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: oh  forgot to mention,  I am trying not to use stringify()... thank you though

Comment: @EmilyScone Can you explain why not? If your problem has any unusual restrictions, those should be explained in the question.

Comment: I'll add another solution a bit later

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the XY problem